# Laravel Socialite: Oauth 2 Rejection Workflow

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, oauth, oauth-2.0, laravel-socialite

I am trying out the "reject" workflow when a user cancels the OAuth Authorization request from the Social (LinkedIn in this case) page

> ClientException in RequestException.php line 111: Client error: `POST
>   https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken` resulted in a `400 Bad
>   Request` response: {"error":"missing_parameter","error_description":"A
>   required parameter \"code\" is missing"}

Controllers have the standard code:

```
public function redirect()
{
    return Socialite::driver('linkedin')->redirect();
}

public function callback()
{
    $providerUser = Socialite::driver('linkedin')->user();
    ...
}
```

It works fine if the user clicks Allow/Accept on the social site. It throws exception when the user cancels.

I am unable to figure out how to handle the user's "Reject" scenario.

Answer (score 1):

In the `callback` function add a `try` `catch` block for exception and do whatever you like to do.

```
try {

    $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    return redirect('redirect'); // This will ask for access from user again. I don't prefer
    // Do whatever you like
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a long search, the solution is to remove the 'r_liteprofile' from scopes and put 'r_basicprofile' in vendor\laravel\socialite\src\Two\LinkedInProvider.php

It should be:
`protected $scopes = ['r_basicprofile', 'r_emailaddress'];`